# What happens if I never receive my CA jury duty summons in the mail?

Tags: california, jury, trial, mail

This question is strictly hypothetical, but what happens if I never receive a Jury Duty Summons in the state of CA in the mail? Theerefore, I miss whatever trial/week I was assigned to,  because I never received the notification in the first place, through no fault of my own?

Comment: They use someone who did turn up.

Comment: I think the question is whether you would be punished for failing to appear.

Comment: How would you ever know that you were summoned?

Answer (score 2):

According to my California county's [Superior Court](https://www.sb-court.org/jury-information/failure-appearrespond-jury-summons), Failure to Appear/Respond to a Jury Summons:

> Pursuant to California Code of Civil Procedure Section 209, any
> prospective juror who has been summoned for service, and who fails to
> respond as directed and be excused from attendance, may be found in
> contempt of court, punishable by fine ($1,500), incarceration (5 days)
> or both.

There's no other information on the Jury webpages about beyond to call them if you miss the summons date. I suspect that if you did call them, they would just schedule for a new date.

I personally know people who have tossed all their jury summons and nothing has happened to them, but that may not hold true for all California counties.

Comment: I am quite certain that failure to receive a summons, if believed by the court, would be a defense to this sanction.

Comment: @ohwilleke isn't that more or less implicit in "if you did call them, they would just schedule for a new date"?

Comment: @phoog Your statement goes to common practice and how the law is administered in fact. My comment goes to the case of someone aggressively seeking to punish you despite the fact that this is atypical, and suggesting that they would not prevail in doing so.